# SCM replication using Hudson

Tags: svn, hudson, replication

Here is my question: Is there any way to replicate a project from svn 'A' to svn 'b' using Hudson?

Here is the context:
We are working on a project using customer's SVN and we want to replicate (automatically), using SCM Hudson's polling, all the committed code to our SVN. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need subversion replication using write through proxy. It is not necessary that you need to use Hudson for that purpose as you can use some simple cron or a windows scheduler to do it. However you can do it with hudson too.

The below link will help setup write through proxy. which would allow you to checkout from local repository and commit to the master repository.

http://www.devx.com/opensource/Article/39525/1763/page/3

BTW, you can also explore git-svn, which will allow you to make local commits and finally do a big bang merge once you are ready for the commit to the master server.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a deep look into the [Subversion book under the keyword svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnsync) which is intended to do replication. But you can't checkin on  the replicated SVN repository, cause it's read-only.